# Enable shared ownership support for an object

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, smart-pointers

I enabled a simple shared ownership for a class with the following control block structure

```
template <class C>
struct Ptr
{
    C* value_ ;
    size_t ref_ ;
    IdType id_ ;
};

Ptr<Payload>* ptr_ ;
```

`value_` is the payload with a shared ownership,

`id_` is a database Id that links value to a database row. It can exist with or without a payload, that's why it's not part of the payload but part of the control block,

`ref_` is the reference counter.

And the following functions allowing to take ownership and releasing it:

```
template<class C>
void ptr<C>::free()
{
    if(ptr_)
    {
        ptr_->ref_-- ;
        if(ptr_->ref_==0)
        {
            delete ptr_->value_ ;
            delete ptr_ ;
            ptr_ = nullptr ;
        }
    }
}

template<class C>
void ptr<C>::take()
{
    if(ptr_)
        ptr_->ref_++ ;
}
```

This works well but I need to go further as it does not cover my needs:

1. This is not conform to the `shared_ptr` standard as my control block is not thread safe and my ownership manipulation is not atomic
2. I need to add weak ownership support. This will be quite easy as I just need to have a second counter and delete the control block only if all counters falls to 0.

My needs for the ownership behavior are already covered by C++11 smart pointers but they are not designed to be inherited and there is no way to customize the control block.

I tried to understand how the atomicity was handled with both boost and standard library but this is relatively cryptic for now.

So the question is simple, is there a way with Boost or STL to enable shared ownership support inside object core design, and by this way be compliant with C++ standards?

Comment: I explored this solution but intrusive_ptr does not implement thread safety by default. I found this article http://www.philten.com/boost-smartptr-mt/ explaining how to hack it, I'm giving a try in this direction.

Comment: "there is no way to customize the control block" Actually there is. You can stash whatever you want in a custom deleter, and retrieve it with `get_deleter`.